# Nullable object must have a value when deviding

Tags: entity-framework-core, sum, automapper, icollection

I have the following mapping:

```
 .ForMember(dest => dest.AskerAverageRating, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
      src.ReviewsReceived != null?
      ((float)src.ReviewsReceived.Sum(r => r.Rating) / (float)src.ReviewsReceived.Count()) : 0))
```

This alone:

```
(float)src.ReviewsReceived.Sum(r => r.Rating)
```

Works.

This alone:

```
(float)src.ReviewsReceived.Count()
```

Also works.

Devided however, they give the following error:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
```

Why???

Here are the relevant Properties and entities:

This is the destination

```
public float AskerAverageRating { get; set; }
```

These is the source:

```
public ICollection<Review> ReviewsReceived { get; set; }
```

This is `Review`:

```
public class Review
{
    ..
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    ..
```

..And I found nothing funky in the DB.

Comment: What if you use `Average`?

Comment: You're not making the most of your bounty if you don't respond to comments. Another thing is that it may help to take AutoMapper out of the equation and show the code as a simple `Select`. That will make the question more accessible to people not knowing AutoMapper and help you get answers. And it rules out any AutoMapper involvement in the issue, however unlikely.

Comment: Agree with @Gert comments. The question is missing important details. Are you using `Map` or `ProjectTo`? `src.ReviewsReceived != null` condition is very strange, it is never true for server side query, so looks like you are using `Map`. Then, are you sure you `Include`-d the navigation property? Have you debugged which code is throwing NRE? Can we see the exception stack trace? Can you provide [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing parentheses around `src.ReviewsReceived != null`.

Please find working solution here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gaGZp0